# GCC on Mac OSX--multiple versions of gcc

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I think I have several versions of gcc installed on my Mac OSX.
Right now, when I type gcc --version. I got gcc (GCC) 4.6.0 20100703 (experimental)
.
But I want to use earlier version gcc.
The thing is, i don't know how to find the path of older version gcc.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, your `gcc` installations should be in `/usr/bin/`. So, for example, to use gcc 4.2, you'd use `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2` to compile your files. You can do `ls /usr/bin/gcc*` to see which ones you have installed.

**EDIT:**
If `gcc` isn't installed in the default path (i.e., `/usr/bin/`), then you can execute `locate gcc` in the terminal to find where it is located.